# Android's sound (card?) randomly turned off with AudioTrack

Tags: android, audio

I’m using `AudioTrack` to play some sounds that I mix myself. Really short sounds, like 1 second in length, one every, say, 3 seconds.

Fairly standard way to create the `AudioTrack`:

```
AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
  4410 * 2 * 2 /* 100 ms stereo */, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

And to play:

```
at.play()
at.write(mix, 0, mix.size)
at.stop()
```

Most of the time this works flawlessly. However, sometimes—especially when headphones/external speakers are plugged in—the sound card is turned off. I can notice the exact moment, because usually, when nothing is played and the sound is on, there’s some really quiet white noise present.

So the sound is turned off, the white noise disappears completely, and a few next sounds are not played at all. After about 2-3 following tries, the sound card comes back to life.

Also, sometimes the first milliseconds of the sound stutter and are repeated. As if the card was too slow in its coming back?

What is causing this weird behavior? How can I circumvent it? I’m by no means attached to `AudioTrack`, if there’s a better alternative, that will let me play an array of `short`s, then I’m all ears.

---

Edit: these might be related:

- http://grokbase.com/t/gg/android-developers/11c6kk6dqx/audiotrack-wont-play-quiet-sounds-below-approx-15-db
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410306/quiet-audio-not-played-at-all-via-audiotrack-api

Comment: Did you consider using SoundPool instead?

Comment: @JoxTraex, how do I load a `short` array of samples into a `SoundPool`? See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor,%20int%29

Comment: Soundpool is not limited by length (outside of ridiculous large bounds probably) but seems like it would work. Not sure why you have to use AudioTrack? Is there a technical reason? However; coming out of the detail level, its also possible that its just a problem with YOUR particular device. Have you tried another device and confirmed the same behavior? All devices are NOT made equally from the perspective of the framework and/or drivers. Some may have problems that others don't. Also another thing in your reference you mentioned about amplitude of the sound, not length.. I dont see the conn.

Comment: @JoxTraex, I was asking about a concrete method in `SoundPool` that can be used to load an array of `short`s. Because I see none in the documentation. :-) In the last sentece of the question, I’m clearly stating that I do *not* have to use `AudioTrack` and I’ll be happy to use anything that works. This happens on all 3 devices I tested on.

Comment: You have to build N Soundpool objects, all it is, is just a pointer to a file. When you need it user play() after you've setup the SoundPool object of course. Simply you can have an ArrayList<SoundPool> objects and play them as necessary. if that makes sense.

Comment: @JoxTraex, hardly, because I have **no sound file**. Just an array of `short`s, samples **generated** on the fly. :-)

Comment: I see, well that was unclear from your post you said 'Really short sounds," not shorts generated on the fly. Your're technically streaming it to the speaker, in which case I think you are constrained to have to use AudioTrack.

Comment: @JoxTraex, doesn’t my use of backticks in “an array of `short`s” imply `short[]`? Still, the original question remains open.